# Rails Session Timeout for Custom Authentication System

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a custom authentication system (I can't use Devise or any other gem). Everything is working as expected so far. However, I am having a problem with the Session Timeout. I have a couple of requirements that I need to meet:

- Prompt the User when their session is about to expire
- Destroy the session if there is no user input after a certain period of time
- If the session times out, then redirect the user back to the login page

I am trying to meet these by using one of the many Jquery/Bootstrap examples. The problem I am facing is that it asks for a Keep Alive URL. I do not know what to put in this path. Should I just search for the remember_token or do I have to perform an action at the Keep Alive Url? What ideally should the Keep Alive Url be?

Any advise/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin might be helpful:
https://github.com/maxfierke/jquery-sessionTimeout-bootstrap

The documentation for keepAliveUrl on that page says: "This resource should do something innocuous that would keep the session alive, which will depend on your server-side platform."

I think in rails just accessing the session in the course of handling the request should be sufficient.